# Admission Ticket for Universal Studios

Tags: tickets, los-angeles, universal-studios

I am going to LA for 2 day trip i.e. on 11th November and 12th November. I am thinking to spend whole one day in Universal Studios.

I saw there is one 105$ ticket which is General Admission ticket for Adults. What are the things this ticket includes? Does it include all rides free of cost, food, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A general admission ticket includes all rides, but not food, parking, souvenirs, or other purchases. There's also a (substantial) additional fee for [a VIP experience](https://www.universalstudioshollywood.com/vip-experience/vip-experience-overview?__source=topnav) or for a front-of-the-line pass. But general admission includes all the regular rides and attractions.

It's sometimes possible to [find discounted tickets online](https://www.mousesavers.com/california-discounts-deals/universal-studios-hollywood-discounts-and-deals/#tickets), though the discounts on single-day tickets aren't usually all that much. But if you're a AAA or Costco member, it's worth comparing prices (be careful to make sure the tickets can be used the day you want to use them), and you can search for discounted tickets online or check with your hotel.